# Cannot pass []datastore.PropertyList to GetMulti function (datastore: src has invalid type)

Tags: google-app-engine, dictionary, go, google-cloud-datastore, slice

I have wrote the following function, since passing map going to be dynamic I'm using `datastore.PropertyList`. Single insert works with `PropertyList`, but in `Multiple` insert an error is displayed as "datastore: src has invalid type"

**Edited and added the full source**

Where I have gone wrong?

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"golang.org/x/net/context"
"golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
"google.golang.org/cloud"
"google.golang.org/cloud/datastore"
"io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
//Single Insert

// var map0 map[string]interface{}
// map0 = make(map[string]interface{})
// map0["Id"] = "600"
// map0["Name"] = "Prasad"
// map0["Age"] = 23

// setOneDataStore(map0)

//Multiple Insert

var allMaps []map[string]interface{}
allMaps = make([]map[string]interface{}, 2)

var map1 map[string]interface{}
map1 = make(map[string]interface{})
map1["Id"] = "700"
map1["Name"] = "Jay"
map1["Age"] = 23

var map2 map[string]interface{}
map2 = make(map[string]interface{})
map2["Id"] = "800"
map2["Name"] = "Peter"
map2["Age"] = 30

allMaps[0] = map1
allMaps[1] = map2

setManyDataStore(allMaps)
}

func getDataStoreClient() (client *datastore.Client, err error) {

keyFile := "JAYWORLD-30y4f7c347pq.json"
projectID := "jay-world"

jsonKey, err := ioutil.ReadFile(keyFile)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
} else {
    conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(
        jsonKey,
        datastore.ScopeDatastore,
        datastore.ScopeUserEmail,
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        ctx := context.Background()
        client, err = datastore.NewClient(ctx, projectID, cloud.WithTokenSource(conf.TokenSource(ctx)))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
    }
}

return
}

func setManyDataStore(Objects []map[string]interface{}) {
ctx := context.Background()
client, err := getDataStoreClient() //have connection code in another function
ctx = datastore.WithNamespace(ctx, "CompanyA")

if err == nil {

    var keys []*datastore.Key
    keys = make([]*datastore.Key, len(Objects))
    var propArray []datastore.PropertyList
    propArray = make([]datastore.PropertyList, len(Objects))

    for index := 0; index < len(Objects); index++ {
        keys[index] = datastore.NewKey(ctx, "users", Objects[index]["Id"].(string), 0, nil)

        props := datastore.PropertyList{}

        for key, value := range Objects[index] {
            props = append(props, datastore.Property{Name: key, Value: value})
        }
        propArray[index] = props
    }

    if _, err := client.PutMulti(ctx, keys, propArray); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Success!")
    }

} else {
    fmt.Println("Connection Failed")
}
}

func setOneDataStore(Object map[string]interface{}) {

ctx := context.Background()
client, err := getDataStoreClient() //have connection code in another function
ctx = datastore.WithNamespace(ctx, "CompanyA")

key := datastore.NewKey(ctx, "users", Object["Id"].(string), 0, nil)

props := datastore.PropertyList{}

for key, value := range Object {
    props = append(props, datastore.Property{Name: key, Value: value})
}

_, err = client.Put(ctx, key, &props)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
} else {
    fmt.Println("Success!")
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error indicates: `"datastore: src has invalid type"` the value you pass as `src` (`&propArray`) has invalid type.

You can't pass a value of type `*[]datastore.PropertyList` as the `src` parameter of [`Client.PutMulti()`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud/datastore#Client.PutMulti). Quoting from the doc:

> `src` must satisfy the same conditions as the `dst` argument to `GetMulti`.

And the conditions of `dst` at [`Client.GetMulti()`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud/datastore#Client.GetMulti):

> `dst` must be a `[]S`, `[]*S`, `[]I` or `[]P`, for some struct type `S`, some interface type `I`, or some non-interface non-pointer type `P` such that `P` or `*P` implements `PropertyLoadSaver`. If an `[]I`, each element must be a valid `dst` for `Get`: it must be a struct pointer or implement `PropertyLoadSaver`.

So you can't pass a pointer to slice, but you can and you should pass a slice (drop the address `&` operator):

```
if _, err := client.PutMulti(ctx, keys, propArray); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
} else {
    fmt.Println("Success!")
}
```

**Note:** Seemingly you are creating keys with specific ids (which is the `index`). But if both the key name and id is the zero value, that is considered to be an incomplete key. Your first key will be an incomplete key as your `index` starts with `0`. You might want to use different ids than the index.

Comment: I removed the address operator and now im getting "datastore: invalid entity type" error.

Comment: @PrasadJay Are you sure you're not mixing imports? It should be `"google.golang.org/cloud/datastore"`, and not `"google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"` nor `"appengine/datastore"`.

Comment: @PrasadJay Also initialize your `props` like this (because if there are no key-value pairs in the map, `nil` will be problematic): `props := datastore.PropertyList{}`

Comment: No I'm using cloud/datastore import. I edited the question and posted the full source file. In there single insert works so cannot be a connection issue. Can you identify where I have go wrong? I'm really confused since there are no nil values even.

Comment: I solved this using []interface{} rather than []datastore.PropertyList and correcting
    propArray[index] = props
to
    propArray[index] = &props


.Marking this answer as solved since it helped me so much. Thank you icza.

Comment: @PrasadJay Thanks for the response, the problem may be that `PropertyList` itself doesn't implement `PropertyLoadSaver` interface, only `*PropertyList`. So I think your example would also work if `propArray` would be of type `[]*datastore.PropertyList`. Filling it: `propArray[index] = &props`. Can you try this one too?

Comment: Tried it. Gives me "datastore: src has invalid type" error again. But with []interface works.